# how to define local spring beans in mule

Tags: spring, mule

I have several flows in my `mule-config.xml` but some beans only makes sense to say one flow. Is there a way to define a bean local to a flow. I understand that I can define an inline bean like below:

```
<custom-transformer name="soapFaultTransformer" class="com.xxx.xx.transformer.VelocityMessageTransformer">
    <spring:property name="velocityEngine"  ref="velocityEngine" />
    <spring:property name="templateName"    value="soapFault.vm" />
    <spring:property name="beanClass">
        <spring:bean class="com.xxx.services.xx.Soap11Fault">
                <spring:property name="faultCode"   value="Client" />
                <spring:property name="faultString" value="Invalid Request" />
                <spring:property name="detail"      value="..." />
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:property>
</custom-transformer>
```

but the inline `spring bean` is needed to use at 2 places in a single flow? Can I still define it in a single place and refer it in 2 places without making it global bean?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think so. What's the problem with global beans?

Comment: As stated, this particular bean makes sense to only 1 flow, then why to make it visible to others...trying to achieve _encapsulation_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David said, it's not possible to declare beans specific to **a single** flow. Declared beans will be available to all flows.

Answer (score 1):

How about gathering all the spring bean necessary for a single flow into a separate spring config file that is imported only by that flow?

Your mule config will look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <spring:import resource="encapsulated-beans.xml" />

    <flow name="flow" >
        ...
    </flow>


</mule>
```

where **encapsulated-beans.xml** will be the config file that includes, for example, your com.xxx.services.xx.Soap11Fault bean

Comment: Please give an example importing a spring file for a particular flow

Comment: but then won't this encapsulated-beans.xml will be available to all flows? How will you make it specific to flow `flow`

Comment: I see your point now and yes by doing this the bean will be available to all flows. I believe that @David was right in the first place when he said it was not possible